# Netty seems to be ignoring encoding

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, netty

I have a netty server running that seems to be ignoring encoding. An error in the d3.js is caused because of the PI symbol. Below is the code that sets the encoding. Even after hardcoding it still doesn't work, any ideas why?

```
RandomAccessFile raf;
try {
  raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
} catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
  sendError(ctx, NOT_FOUND);
  return;
}
long fileLength = raf.length();

HttpResponse response = new DefaultHttpResponse(HTTP_1_1, OK);
setContentTypeHeader(response, file);
setContentLength(response, fileLength);
setDateAndCacheHeaders(response, file);
if (isKeepAlive(request)) {
  response.setHeader(CONNECTION, HttpHeaders.Values.KEEP_ALIVE);
}

// Write the initial line and the header.
ctx.write(response);

// Write the content.
ChunkedFile chunkedFile = new ChunkedFile(raf, 0, fileLength, 8192);
ChannelFuture writeFuture = ctx.write(chunkedFile);

ctx.write(chunkedFile, writeFuture);
```

Here is the `setContentTypeHeader` code:

```
private static void setContentTypeHeader(HttpResponse response, File file) {
String contentType = MimeTypes.getContentType(file.getPath());
response.setHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, contentType);
if (!contentType.equals("application/octet-stream")) {
  response.setHeader(CONTENT_ENCODING, "charset=utf-8");
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

[Content encoding](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.11) is not character encoding, but for compression such as gzip. The character encoding of a response is specified in the [Content-Type header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17).

```
private static void setContentTypeHeader(HttpResponse response, File file) {

    String contentType = MimeTypes.getContentType(file.getPath());

    if (!contentType.equals("application/octet-stream")) {
      contentType += "; charset=utf-8";
    }
    response.setHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, contentType);

}
```